# JAXB Prevent jaxb from serializing with a shared entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jaxb

I have 4 entities,

purchaseRequest - funding - lineItemFunding
purchaseRequest - lineItem - lineItemFunding - funding

I'm using JAXB and `@XmlTransient` in `lineItemFunding` on the `ManyToOne` relationship.

When coming from `purchaseRequest` -> `funding` - I do not want it scanning `lineItemFunding`, but when coming from `purchaseRequest` -> `lineItem` -> `lineItemFunding` -> `Funding`. I want it to do a deep scan of `Funding`. The problem I run into is if I use `@XmlTransient` on the `getFunding()` inside of `lineItemFunding`, things work perfectly, but if I remove it, I get the following error.

```
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: 
A cycle is detected in the object graph. 
This will cause infinitely deep XML: 
org.company.com.entities.Funding@2a2 
-> org.company.com.entities.LineItemFunding@82 
-> org.company.com.entities.Funding@2a2
```

So my question is, how do I prevent it from trying to do a deep scan on lineItemFunding from the funding entity. Below is my source.

PurchaseRequest

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<LineItem> lineItems;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "purchaseRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Funding> fundings;
```

Funding

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "funding", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<LineItemFunding> lineItemFundings;

@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "purchase_request_id", nullable = false)
private PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest;
```

lineItem

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lineItem", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LineItemFunding> lineItemFundings;

@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "purchase_request_id", nullable = false)
private PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest;
```

LineItemFunding

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "line_item_id", nullable = true)
private LineItem lineItem;
```

// need to remove this xmlTransient to deep scan the funding entity from the lineItem direction, but breaks it in the funding direction. Funding does not need to deep scan linItemFunding since lineItemFunding is just a join of funding to the lineItem.

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "funding_id", nullable = true)
private Funding funding;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to avoid using entities used other place else then persistence layer because , they might be waved and depending on the persitence framework used I always had problems with this.
So I used DTO's. (it might be old fashion but it solved the problem)

However recently i saw this so in your case it might help
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/SDO/JPA

Comment: @Chris, thanks Chris, but in this instance, I don't believe this is going to help me. I will however take a look at DTO's next time. I would think there would be some annotation you could apply to your method that would prevent the object from being scanned any further.

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved my own question. I needed to nothing other than remove the @XmlTransient annotation from the @ManyToOne relationship in lineItemFunding and apply the annotation to the @OneToMany relationship in Funding.